# Using PDO SQLSRV with PHP not working

Tags: php, pdo, sqlsrv

I have been trying to get the PDO SQLSRV to work *(in a windows server 2012 R2)* for a while now and have found [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017) on how I'm supposed to set it up so that the drivers load on starting up PHP, but it's not working.

I have located the correct php.ini file (and tested by commenting out some of the other PDO drivers to make sure). I added the appropriate line at the end of the `[ExtensionList]` like this:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

I added several of those, but nothing is working. I check it by running a script with `phpinfo()` to show me what is going on. The extension list looks like this:

```
[ExtensionList]
; extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
; extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_tidy.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll
```

So under PDO should be `mysql` and `sqlsrv`, but I only see the `mysql`.

[image]

Am I missing something?

**Update**

I tried updating the php.ini file so that it has the full path for those extensions, still didn't make any difference.

Architecture=x64, Thread Safety=disabled, PHP Version=7.2.2, Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

**Update II**

I have tried removing all references except the 2 that I need and gave them fully qualified directory paths:

```
[ExtensionList]
; extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
; extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts_x64.dll"
extension="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll"
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_tidy.dll
```

I am still unable to get SQL SRV to work, it still does not show up in the PHPInfo print out.

Are there any other suggestions of what I can try?

**UPDATE**

Yesterday I reinstalled PHP 7.2 (now version 7.2.6) from [here](https://windows.php.net/download#php-7.2-nts-VC15-x64). And reinstalled the Microsoft Drivers 5.2 for PHP for SQL Server from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56729). And updated my php.ini file like this:

```
[ExtensionList]
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_tidy.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
extension="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll"
; extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

To see if that would help or make any difference. The `php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll` still does not load, then `php_pdo_sqlite.dll` did load, and they are both in the same folder as the php_mysqli.dll which also loaded. I have followed the instructions that I found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-php-development?view=sql-server-2017) and nothing seems to be working to get that SQL SRV dll to load.

Comment: @Zhorov Architecture=x64, Thread Safety=disabled, PHP Version=7.2.2

Comment: @Zhorov I don't know, how would I check that?

Comment: @Zhorov it is installed. I don't know what version, but when I tried just now to install ODBC Driver 13.1 I get a message stating that a higher version is already installed.

Comment: Any errors in IIS log file?

Comment: I think you must use php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts_x64.dll. You also need Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server, 64-bit install.
Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Zhorov I do not see any errors in the IIS logs. I have installed the ODBC Driver 17 and already have the php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_x64.dll. I still get the same results.

Comment: It may be a permission issue (try to give read permission to iis user) as you put the files from unknown resource for the server.

Comment: @alalp I'm not sure what you mean, give read permission where to what user? I have `Anonymous Authentication` and `Windows Authentication` both enabled for IIS.

Comment: @Mike I mean dll files. On IIS, CGI module tries to read dlls according to your ini file (correct me if I wrong but, at least those dll files should be read). If IIS user (I mean IUSR or IIS_IUSRS) cannot read these dlls, they cannot be loaded.

Comment: @alalp I checked and the new DLL's that I added have the same permissions as the old ones that were already there for sqllite and mysql. Those 2 I can add and remove at will without a problem, but the sqlsrv ones never work and they are in the same folder.

Comment: @Mike Can you restart IIS and show the content of IIS log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure it out and get it working. I tried to install CakePHP which requires Composer. So while installing Composer I got an error that I had not seen before and posted a question about that. The end result is that I had to reinstall PHP again clean and then update the php.ini so only have the TS versions of PDO SQLSRV.

The other question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268416/how-to-recompile-php-with-either-nts-or-ts)

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumble upon this, if you not uncomment ext dir conf in php.ini it will not load modules, seems simple but many people (including me) noticed, and i expected that PHP would look to it's default dir.