# How to recompile PHP with either NTS or TS?

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

I am trying to get SQLSRV PDO to work with PHP. I run `PHP -v` and get the following error

> Warning: PHP Startup: pdo_sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module
>
> Module compiled with build ID=API20180718,NTS,VC15
>
> PHP compiled with build ID=API20180718,TS,VC15
>
> These options need to match
>
> in Unknown on line 0

I was getting a different error where the dates in the IDs didn't match, but I have fixed that by getting the current version of PHP (7.2) and putting that in place. It wasn't installed it was a zipped archive that I extracted into the path. Then had to copy the correct *php.ini* file in as well.

Now I get the above error when running `php -v` instead of seeing the php version information displayed.

I am trying to install CakePHP. I have gotten to the point where I'm installing composer. I get this same error when trying to install composer.

All of this is on my web server: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard x64

How do I fix this so that I can install Composer?

Comment: You just need to use the TS(Thread Safe) version of `pdo_sqlsrv` and anything else as well as you are running on Windows

Comment: @RiggsFolly How do I get the `Module` to be TS as well?

Comment: Where ever you downloaded the SQL Server modules there is either a slection option or both come in that same package and you pick the one you want to use

Comment: Where did you get the SQLSRV PDO from

Comment: That did it. I made the update in my *php.ini* to have only the TS load and now it is working. Put that in an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are on Windows, you need the TS (Thread Safe) version of the dll and not the NTS (Not Thread Safe) version.

Make sure that the `php.ini` file is loading only the TS extension.